# Laravel mail is sending email twice when added bcc

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I am trying to send email with **Bcc**, but I have noticed that **SwiftMailer** is sending emails twice (one with Bcc and the other without it), and I removed bcc it's working fine without duplicated mails.

**mailController.php**

```
class mailController extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */      
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {   
        return $this->from('test@gmail.com', 'test')
        ->view('portal.confirmation')
        ->subject('test Email')
        ->bcc('email@gmail.com','wahdan');
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
```

**Update**

This issue happen only in local environment ,but in production it's working perfect without any duplicated emails.

Comment: [Check this article](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#setting-bcc-recipients)

Comment: @user2486 Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: The piece of code you provided is not helping. Apart from that I don't think that mailController should extend Mailable.

Comment: According to Laravel documentation , any mail controller is extending Mailable class , also what other information that i should add it to my question ?

Comment: @wahdan Have you set **Universal To**  for your `config/mail.php`?

Comment: @yrv16 yes, also i have noticed something weird , this issue is happen only in local environment ,but in production it's working perfect without any duplicated emails.

Comment: @wahdan About production it's really strange. So, I was testing your situation and I can say that if set **Universal To** then it happens but if not set it will be only one email (without duplicate). Besides, it happens in **Laravel 5.3** but in **Laravel 5.5** it's correct even with **Universal To** set. Here is some similar discussion [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16705).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you BCC an email and send it through mailtrap.io, you will receive two copies of the email in your mailbox. If there are two BCCs, you will receive three copies, etc. The emails will look identical (including the "To:").

This behavior is specific to mailtrap.io, not Laravel (i.e., it is not on the sending side).

If the number of duplicate emails is the same as the number of BCCs plus the original, I think you can be confident that is the reason.

This answer assumes that you are using mailtrap.io as your SMTP server locally, but not in production.

Comment: yes i have noticed that before and i forgot to add my answer , thank you

Comment: When you open the 'raw' version in Mailtrap, you can see which copy sent as 'bcc'.

Comment: @SCruz I receive more than 1 copy?

Comment: same for mailhog too for me.

Comment: same for aws ses too for me. However, when i tried in local, it works fine, but when i tried in ubuntu ec2 server, it sends twice